# Can "Contract concluded" mean that it's been agreed upon?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

I am a bit baffled by the phrase "Contract concluded between party A and party B" used in certain official papers originally forged in foreign language. To me it sound like the contract has already ended and is no longer in effect.

The intended meaning should be "Contract was agreed upon between..." so I'm wondering if it is a valid phrase to use here? If not, what's the correct way?

Also if the verb conclude is correct here shouldn't be used in passive, i.e. "Contract WAS concluded between..."?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **conclude (FINISH)**:
> to complete an official agreement or task, or arrange a business deal
> [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/conclude)
>
> **conclude [with object]**
> Formally and finally settle or arrange (an agreement)
> ‘*an attempt to conclude a ceasefire*’
> ‘*Negotiations to conclude a new agreement failed.*’
> [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/conclude)

As you will see from the excerpts above, one meaning of **conclude** is to finalise / complete / agree / settle a business or other multi-party agreement. So, the basic answer to your question is 'yes', “Contract concluded” does mean that it's been agreed upon.

If the contract had come to an end, it may have *expired* (*e.g.* on a preset date) or have been *terminated* (*e.g.* by one or both parties, according to criteria set out in the agreement).

Strictly speaking, if you are talking about the event (*i.e.* the making of the agreement) *after* it happened, then there should have been a verb in the past tense to create a proper sentence (e.g. contract *was* concluded).  But the quoted wording (without a verb) would be normal form at the end of the agreement itself, especially immediately above the signatures of the parties to the agreement: here the *present* tense is applicable because they are actually *making the agreement* by adding their signatures.

Answer (score 1):

In legal theory, "formation" of contract is spoken of. In practice, terms such as "execute" or "enter into" are often used. I understand what people (often people translating into English) mean when they say a "contract was concluded", but (as someone who works in the legal sector) I'd say it's not commonly used by native speakers in the legal sector.